# How can i export openshift native resource defination to yaml file, like Project/DeploymentConfig/BuildConfig

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I want export openshift resource defination like CRD YAML file, which import to k8s api server.

`oc get crd project.openshift.io -o yaml > project_crd.yaml`

`kubectl apply -f project_crd.yaml`

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify output format:

oc get crd $WHATEVER **-o yaml** > savedcrd.yaml

Comment: yeah, i know format. my meaning is export openshift native resource, which is built-in openshift apiserver.  example Project resource is openshift only k8s not have